# Display all posts of current viewing tag

Tags: tags

I'm having problems getting all related posts of the current viewing tag. Does anyone know how you can do this dynamic? I want to create a own kind of 'archive' page for this.

Answer (score 2):

Ok .. after searching for a while I figured out what I was doing wrong. I wasn't including custom post types in the loop. I ended up constantly with 'not found'.

Whats the solution:

```
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'blog', 'showposts' => 3, 'orderby' => 'rand') );  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

And it queues all posts with the current viewing tag!

Special thanks to Sven and Kaiser!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function from WordPress with taxonomy parameter.

Comment: Thanks Sven, but how do I get the posts related to the current tag? I've managed to output the single_tag_title(); but don't know how to get the rest..

Comment: So, you need the tag of the current post? You can get the tags with the function get_the_tags() (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags)

Comment: Nope sven, This is what I did:

When viewing a post, I click on one of the tags (like Android), i'm going to the tag.php page and want to display all related posts with the tag 'Android'..

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a tag archive for that.

You can grab a term/taxon, then display a link to its archive using [`get_tag_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_tag_link/).

As you can see from the [Template Hierarchy Diagram](http://codex.wordpress.org/File%3aTemplate_Hierarchy.png?utm_source=wordpress-modguide), there're the following tempalte names, that will trigger (in hierarchical & parent/child theme) order:

- `tag-{$slug}.php`
- `tag-{$id}.php`
- `tag.php`
- `archive.php`

There you will have - depending on your URl/Route - the posts available and can proceed them using a plain loop, like the one you can see in the codex. All filters are available, as well as well as all filters like `pre_get_posts`, etc. and Conditional Tags like `is_tag()` that will determine if you're on a tag archive.